# unix awk command not listing multiple matched pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have following pattern of unix variable. I want to search and output based on `'CREATE' , 'TABLE' & ','` pattern

```
a ="CREATE TABLE T1, is my TABLE but , DROP TABLE is not CREATE my TABLE T2, is table" # it may keep going but pattern is same ....
echo $a | awk -F'CREATE' '{print $2}' | awk -F'TABLE' '{print $2}' | awk -F',' '{print $1}'
```

**outputs**

```
T1
```

I want to print

```
T1
T2
...
```

Comment: Is it ok to fetch the names in between a space and a comma?

Comment: @fedorqui : No, text may have the same. so it should follow the term which i specified

Comment: @fedorqui : I updated my question. Please see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data isn't significant, but you can play around with the following idea:

```
awk -v RS=, '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/{print $NF}'
```

**Explaination:**

- We set the `Record Separator` to `,`, so it splits the line at every `,` it sees. As a result your input line is seen as:

  `CREATE TABLE T1`

  `is my TABLE but CREATE my TABLE T2`

  `is table`
- `/TABLE/&&/CREATE` is a regex that look at lines containing the word `TABLE` and `CREATE`. You can include word boundaries to match `TABLE` only and not `CONSTABLE`.
- `print $NF` means print the last field. `NF` is a special `awk` variable that contains number of fields and `$NF` holds the value of last field.

```
$ echo "CREATE TABLE T1, is my TABLE but CREATE my TABLE T2, is table" | awk -v RS=, '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/{print $NF}'
T1
T2
```

Comment: i need to look for CREATE as well. so should it be `/CREATE/TABLE` ?

Comment: what does the $NF mean ?

Comment: it returns `but` along with T1 & T2 ; `$ echo "CREATE TABLE T1, is my TABLE but , DROP TABLE is not CREATE my TABLE T2, is table"  | awk -v RS=, '/CREATE|TABLE/{print $NF}'
T1
but
T2
`

Comment: Syntax error in SOLARIS machine : `-bash-3.00$ echo "CREATE TABLE T1, is my TABLE but CREATE my TABLE T2, is table" | awk -v RS=, '/TABLE/{print $NF}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
-bash-3.00$
`

Comment: i am in a different path. how should i use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

Comment: I may have databasename prefixed with it ; so i need search for dot (.) as well. `CREATE my TABLE res.T2,`

Comment: @logan Run the command like `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v RS=, -v FS="[. ]" '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/{print $NF}'`

Comment: In the output, how to print the text that does not start with 'X' ; in this same example, T1 & T2 is output. if it return X1,T1,T2 then i want to print only T1 & T2 only. `ignore words starting with X1`

Comment: @logan `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -v RS=, -v FS="[. ]" '/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&&$NF!~/^X/{print $NF}'`

Comment: i tried with this `'/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&&$NF!~/^STG/{print $NF}'` it is still printing tables starting STG

Comment: If you need to skip multiple characters, then use them in `character class []`. Eg. `/TABLE/&&/CREATE/&&$NF!~/^[STG]/{print $NF}`

Comment: what does the -v mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Will be easier with grep:

```
grep -oP 'CREATE .*?TABLE \K\w+' <<< "$a"
T1
T2
```

Comment: its not returning anything.
`$ a="CREATE TABLE T1, is my TABLE but , DROP TABLE is not CREATE my TABLE T2, is table"
$ grep -oP 'CREATE .*?TABLE \K\w+' <<< "$a"
$
`

Comment: I am working in Linux box. its not returning anything

Comment: in bash solaris machine it says `-bash-3.00$ grep -oP 'CREATE .*?TABLE \K\w+' <<< "$a"
grep: illegal option -- o
grep: illegal option -- P
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
-`

Comment: Your grep probably doesn't support `-P` option.

Comment: so whats the replacement ?>

Comment: Upgrade your grep package.